# Finding ship manifests for immigrants to Argentina in early 1900s?

Tags: immigration, manifest, 1900s-decade, argentina

I am looking for a family that emigrated from Poland to Argentina around 1901. I found a transcription of the ship's (SS Georg, sailed from Libau to Buenos Aires) [manifest](https://web.archive.org/web/20121013005229/http://www.pruzhanydistrict.com.ar/people_other/grodno_argent13.htm) on which they arrived (the site in question combines transcripts from several manifests), but I would like to see the images of the original manifest to see what else might be there. I was not able to find this ship in the otherwise excellent collection maintained by the [Immigrant Ships Transcribers Guild](http://immigrantships.net/newcompass/non_am_pass/nonam_pass/index_southamerica.html).

Where else should I look to find this manifest?

Answer (score 10):

To my knowledge, images of ship manifests from Argentina are not online.

[Centro de Estudios Migratorios Latinoamericanos](http://www.cemla.com/) (CEMLA) has a [searchable database](http://www.cemla.com/busqueda.php) of the arrivals in Buenos Aires.  The website is in Spanish.  Here's a translated description of the records that are available:

> The CEMLA database contains data of the arrivals to the port of Buenos Aires of passengers and immigrants who arrived in the period 1882-1932, 1938-1945, 1947, 1948, 1949 (partial) and 1950. There is little data from 1933-1937 because the books are now inaccessible.
>
> * Data available are: surname, given name, nationality, marital status, age at arrival, profession, religion, port of departure, ship name, arrival date (and in some cases family members accompanying him on this trip.)
>
> * Depending on the state of conservation of the lists. The state of destruction of some books has precluded recovery.
>
> The birthplace started getting recorded in 1923. Except for some isolated records from 1910, we do not have information about the province or municipality of birth of immigrant arrivals until 1922.
>
> (Source: http://www.cemla.com/datos.html)

CEMLA has apparently been digitizing records, so you may want to email them to ask if they're able to provide copies of the manifest pages or if there are plans to make them available online.

Comment: Thanks. I remember looking through this site a while ago, and coming up empty. I will try to contact them directly, as you suggest.

Comment: I contacted CEMLA, but they said that they did not have the ship I was interested in, and that "a great number of ships manifests corresponding to 1901 where destroyed or missing when started preserving the information in our data base back in 1992."

Comment: Gene, you might want to contact the Pruzhany group that has the transcription and ask what their source was.  The originals must have been available at some point for them to transcribe the data.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I got the transcription... they are a bit disorganized at the moment. I will see if I can get anybody's attention over there.